# How to call oracle procedure "sdo_geometry"

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial

I have a procedure in oracle package.
How I can call procedure? How to write place "SDO_GEOMETRY"

```
select SEARCH_PKG.GET_FEATURE_DATA('ELECTRIC_ENTAKAYAN_500', PUBLIC.SDO_GEOMETRY, 25000, 'am') from dual
```

Comment: is it a stored procedure or a stored function? The `GET_` prefix suggests that it's a function, rather than a procedure.

Comment: SDO_GEOMETRY Is a type, not a variable. What arguments does the get_feature_data procedure require?

Comment: `PROCEDURE get_feature_data (
      p_layer_i     IN geo_atrib_tables.table_name%TYPE
    , p_geom        IN SDO_GEOMETRY
    , p_buff_i      IN NUMBER
    , p_loc_i       IN adm_locales.locale%TYPE  := adm_translation.getGvcLocale()
    , kursor        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR--refCursor
)
AS`

Comment: Well then you need to pass an object of that type, not the type itself.